# SQlite exception cannot connect to database after moving Solution folder to new computer

Tags: c#, system.data.sqlite

I am pretty new to coding with C# and SQlite, and this is my first post on Stack Overflow, so any advise would be appreciate.

I have created a Winforms database app to track assessment scores. Everything works great when I run it from inside Visual Studio or from the .exe in the debug folder.

A sample of my code for the SQLite connection is below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SQLite;

namespace Training_Assessment_Tracker
{
    public partial class frmOperatorManagement : Form
    {
        SQLiteConnection myConnection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source = C:\\Users\\matt_\\OneDrive\\Documents\\C# Projects\\Training Assessment Tracker\\Training Assessment Tracker\\Assessment Tracking.db");
        public frmOperatorManagement()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void frmOperatorManagement_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ReadData();
            ButtonState();
            TextBoxState(false);
            FillDeparmentComboBox();
            FillEmployedBy();
            FillEmployedStatus();
            dtpDateLeft.CustomFormat = " ";
            dtpDateLeft.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
        }

        // Database Methods
        public void ReadData()
        {
            myConnection.Open();
            var datatable = new DataTable();
            string commandText = "SELECT * FROM Operator";
            SQLiteDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(commandText, myConnection);
            myDataAdapter.Fill(datatable);
            dgvOperators.DataSource = datatable;
            myConnection.Close();
        }
```

I then change the path to the Assessment Tracking.db, to the path it would be on a different computer. The solution was rebuilt, saved and copied. The whole solution folder was pasted to the desktop on the second computer.

Please below for the new path:

```
public partial class frmOperatorManagement : Form
    {
        SQLiteConnection myConnection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source = C:\\Users\\matthew.roberts\\Desktop\\Training Assessment Tracker\\Training Assessment Tracker\\Assessment Tracking.db");
        public frmOperatorManagement()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void frmOperatorManagement_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ReadData();
            ButtonState();
            TextBoxState(false);
            FillDeparmentComboBox();
            FillEmployedBy();
            FillEmployedStatus();
            dtpDateLeft.CustomFormat = " ";
            dtpDateLeft.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
        }
```

When running the app from the .exe in the debug folder on the second computer, I get SQLite exception 14: cannot connect to database. The strange thing is the file path name in the exception text is the file path of the database on the development computer.

Please see the exception text below (I block quote the filepath):

************** Exception Text **************

```
code = CantOpen (14), message = System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException (0x800007FF): unable to open 
database file
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.Open(String strFilename, String vfsName, SQLiteConnectionFlags 
   connectionFlags, SQLiteOpenFlagsEnum openFlags, Int32 maxPoolSize, Boolean usePool)
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection.Open()
   at Training_Assessment_Tracker.frmOperatorManagement.ReadData() in ***

> C:\Users\matt_\OneDrive\Documents\C# Projects\Training Assessment
> Tracker\Training Assessment Tracker\OperatorManagement.cs:line 37

***
   at Training_Assessment_Tracker.frmOperatorManagement.frmOperatorManagement_Load(Object sender, 
   EventArgs e) in C:\Users\matt_\OneDrive\Documents\C# Projects\Training Assessment Tracker\Training 
   Assessment Tracker\OperatorManagement.cs:line 24
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr 
   lparam)
```

What am I missing?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Matt

Comment: It's on a different computer, you'll probably need to change your path from this `C:\\Users\\matthew.roberts\\Desktop` to something like this `\\Computer-Name\\Users\\matthew.roberts\\Desktop`

Comment: Did you copy the database file (as seen in the connection string) with the code?

Comment: And if you do use @LV98's idea, make sure you allow network sharing/access of that folder.

Comment: Thanks for such quick responses. @ gunr2171 I copies the database file with whole solution. I can open the database in DB browser with no issues. @ LV98 and gunr2171 thanks for the suggestion I shall try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to resolve the issue.
I have been adding files through windows explorer and not through visual studio.
I have now included in the project the Assessment Tracking.db and changed it properties:

- Build Action: From "Content" to "None"
- Copy to output directory: From "Do not Copy" to "Copy if newer".

I cleaned the project and rebuilt it. Now the database copies to the Debug folder and works with relative path reference:

```
SQLiteConnection("Data Source = .\\Assessment Tracking.db");
```

Now I can connect to the database and see the data in the datagridviews on various forms. I have tested this by copying to a new computer and onto a networked server and running the app from both locations. It worked both times.

@LV98 and @gunr2171 , thank you for you assistance :)